# How to collect all models whose data are updated in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

To avoid `creating` and then `dropping` all tables when running tests, I want to collect the models whose tables need to be cleared.

But the only event APIs I know can only be registered on the *model* level, I wonder if I can register a global `before_commit` event handler, and take note of the related tables in it.

Comment: Instead of dropping tables have you investigated [alembic](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/rel_0_7/)?  It allows you to migrate tables even if there is data in it.